# decomposing positive integer into more integers such that sum same as original

Tags: algorithm

Got an interview question today,which i was unable to solve
Looking for your advice on same

- decomposition of a positive integer M is a set of unique positive integers whose sum is M
- ex : 7 = 1+6 = 2+5 = 3+4 = 1+2+4

Need to write a function which calculates all such unique combinations

Comment: The technical term for this is "integer partition" doing a search with this keyword will give you a lot of ideas.

Comment: What about this: http://jeromekelleher.net/partitions.php

Comment: @yossico: Strictly speaking, the algorithms in that link are for unique partitions, not for unique partitions of unique integers. However, the two problems are highly related, so it could be the basis for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to print them? then, something like this:

```
int a[100]; a[0] = 0; //to store composition

void rec(int x, int p) {
   for ( int i = a[p-1]+1; i <= x; i++ )
       if (x - i > i ) {
           a[p] = i;
           rec(x - i, p+1);
        } else {
           a[p] = x;
           //print if needed
           for ( int j = 1; j <= p; j++ )
               cout << a[j] << ' ';
           cout << endl;
           return;
        }
}
```

and than call

```
rec(n, 1);
```